# How to disable a rule action?

Tags: rules, actions

When creating rules I use to create **System Message actions** to print out some values for checking purposes. Then in production I'd like to disable instead of deleting these actions. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Active issue in http://drupal.org/node/1288874 . I suggest to follow issue queue for updates .

Comment: thanks, I just posted my message for that request. It would be really useful. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, i Agree....